# Polynomial\Pseudo-Polynomial Algorithm for Subset-Sum Problem with float and target sum or nearest sum to the target sum

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

I want to know that is there exist an algorithm to calculate "all possible combinations" of a sorted list (float and duplicates allowed) with a target sum and if there isn't any combination equal to the target sum, the algorithm return "all possible combinations" of nearest sum (lower bound) to the target sum in polynomial or pseudo-polynomial time.
I checked Balsub Algorithm "Linear Time Algorithms for Knapsack Problems with Bounded Weights" and also "A Faster Pseudopolynomial Time Algorithm for Subset Sum" with polynomial time but I'm not sure whether these problems are same regarding time-complexity.

This is an example:

`Sorted List: {1.5, 2.25, 3.75, 3.81}
Target = 3.79
Results: {1.5, 2.25}, {3.75} = 3.75`

Thanks

Comment: Are they limited to two decimal places after the decimal point?

Comment: @Fei Xiang Yes, it can be also with one decimal.

Comment: Then just read in the numbers as if you multiplied everything by 100. This should work as long as the numbers are small enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of.

The idea of the usual pseudopolynomial solution for subset sum with small integers is that while there are a very large number of combinations, there are relatively few sums to consider.  So I can store, by subset sum, a list of which last index and value we arrived at that sum at.  I can then find my target answer, and walk the data structure backwards to create a list of the intermediate subset sums and index+values which were on the way to the final target answer.  That gives us a data structure that represents a finite state machine to produce all possible answers.  We can walk it forward with dynamic programming to either produce one answer, or a count of answers, or recursively enumerate it to give all answers.  (Knowing that all answers is usually a very long list.)

The problem with floating point is that now there are a very large number of subsets AND a very large number of intermediate sums.  That trick doesn't work.  You can round numbers off into buckets, and produce approximate answers that are close to your target.  But they will be approximate, and the right answer remains a needle in a haystack.

Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @btilly. So if I modify my problem and bound the decimal to one or two after decimal point for both list and target is it possible to solve it in P/P-P?

Comment: @Ali Yes.  But you'll only be producing an approximate answer to the original problem.  However a technical note.  I would recommend multiplying then truncating first so that you are dealing with integers.  That is because in floating point calculations, adding together fractions is not guaranteed to produce precise answers.

Comment: Actually I don't want to implement the algorithm, I want to use these papers to show that my problem can be solved in P/P-P time. What do you mean by approximate? It means that it is possible that the algorithm cannot find the target sum or nearest sum to target sum but it can find "all possible combinations" to the approximate target sum? And the last question is, do you know what is the best time-complexity for solving this problem?

Comment: @Ali By approximate I mean that you'll produce subsets whose sum is close to the chosen target, but you don't necessarily find the best.  For the best known you'd have to ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com/, but this is an NP-complete problem.